# Problem installing my own package in Editable mode

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I try to install my own package by using the command: `pip install -e .` but I get a very long error message which is attached at the end.
I tried to run the code on vscode and pycharm but the problem remains the same.
I started the package on a first computer which versions are:
`setuptools: 59.5.0 pip: 21.3.1 python: 3.9`
On the second computer I had this problem.
Its versions are:
`setuptools: 58.1.0 pip: 21.2.4 python: 3.9`
Then I tried on a fresh third computer with the same files and it worked just fine, versions:
`setuptools: 47.1.0 pip: 20.1.1 python: 3.8`
I'm attaching the relevant files that might be helpful in order to understand the issue.
The OS of all the computers is Windows, but the first and third are English version and the second computer is not. I think that maybe it is the problem, but I'm not sure and have no idea how to fix this if it is indeed the case here

`setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup()
```

`setup.cfg`:

```
[metadata]
name=Mice
version=0.0.1
author=J. Random Hacker
author_email=jrh@example.com

[options]
packages=mice
install_requires=
    typing_extensions >= 4.0.1

python_requires = >=3.6
package_dir =
    =src
long_description=open('README.txt').read()

[options.extras_require]
testing =
    pytest>=6.0

[options.package_data]
mice = py.typed

[flake8]
max-line-length=180

ignore=
    F401 # A module has been imported but is not used anywhere in the file.
    E302 # Two blank lines are expected between functions and classes.
```

The full error I'm getting is:

```
(myenv) D:\local_github\Mice>pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///D:/local_github/Mice
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 173, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 315, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 75, in resolve
    collected = self.factory.collect_root_requirements(root_reqs)
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 471, in collect_root_requirements
    req = self._make_requirement_from_install_req(
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 433, in _make_requirement_from_install_req
    cand = self._make_candidate_from_link(
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 189, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._editable_candidate_cache[link] = EditableCandidate(
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 321, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 227, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 331, in _prepare_distribution
    return self._factory.preparer.prepare_editable_requirement(self._ireq)
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 622, in prepare_editable_requirement
    dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 60, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(finder, build_isolation)
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\sdist.py", line 34, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self._setup_isolation(finder)
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\sdist.py", line 61, in _setup_isolation
    self.req.build_env = BuildEnvironment()
  File "D:\local_github\Mice\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\build_env.py", line 103, in __init__
    fp.write(textwrap.dedent(
  File "D:\yohai_new\python_folder\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 589-591: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: We need more details. I can only assume you are packaging with _setuptools_, if yes we might need to see your `setup.py` file? What Python interpreter, OS, etc. are you using? -- Also please use `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install -e .` to ensure you are using the correct Python interpreter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've updated my question. Is it better now?

Comment: Maybe add the complete error message.

Comment: @sinoroc I edited the question, if something important is still missing just say so :) thanks a lot in advance

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid... Seems like something with encoding, but what? Hard to say. I found a [somewhat similar issue here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9054), maybe some of the workarounds could apply to your case. -- Are the paths in the error output exact or edited before pasting here? -- Otherwise, the usual: try to update pip and/or setuptools.

Comment: The paths in the error output are copy pasted so it is exactly the same. Tried to update both pip and setuptools to pip-21.3.1 and setuptools-60.5.0 but same issue again :(

Comment: According to the similar issues on pip's Github, it might be something with the path containing unusual characters, that is why I asked. So you could try installing Python at a different path and moving code at different path as well. But current paths seem fine, so I doubt it would really change anything. -- Then, I would recommend you try the workarounds in the linked Github ticket and other similar tickets (setting environment variables, etc.) -- Also you could narrow it down, try with a minimal project created from scratch to eliminate all other possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

The `long_description` key of `setup.cfg` is in the wrong section and its value is not valid.

It should be  in the `[metadata]` section (not in `[options]`) and it should something like the following:

```
[metadata]
# ...
long_description = file: README.txt
long_description_content_type = text/plain
```

---

***References***:

- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html
- https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#description-content-type

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the files, since today I tried to install the same files on a third computer and it worked well.
The only difference from the second computer is that on the second computer the OS is windows but not in English, maybe that's the problem?
I don't see any other difference between the second computer where I got the error and the third computer where it worked fine

Comment: @niroo You need to check what setuptools and pip versions are used on each machine.

Comment: I'm attaching the versions for the two computers where the code worked.  
The second computer's versions which had the issue will be uploaded later today (with the entire error message too).  
Then I will Edit my question with all of the data.
Any more data about my machines is required?

first computer:
setuptools: 59.5.0
pip: 21.3.1
python: 3.9

third computer:
setuptools: 47.1.0
pip: 20.1.1
python: 3.8

Comment: @niroo The problem is very likely in the files. Do what @sinoroc wrote and try specifying the encoding of the README like this: `long_description = file:README.txt
long_description_content_type = text/plain; charset-UTF-8`